# Program to print a circle of given diameter

Tags: turtle-graphics, ucb-logo, logo-lang

I am trying to write a program to print a circle of given diameter in Berkeley logo. I get the input diameter from the user of the program and draw a circle accordingly. But I do not know of any method to display a circle given the diameter. All along I have been using,

```
repeat 36 [fd 10 rt 10]
```

to draw a circle. But it is not what I want. I tried using formulas for diameter, but it is not working. Can anybody please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to find the perimeter first, then divide it by the total number of rotations, then set that as the value of forward in your loop.

E.g.

```
make "d 100
make "p 3.141592654*:d
make "i :p/36
repeat 36[fd :i rt 10]
```

you can have all of them in a single statement as

```
repeat 36[fd 3.141592654*:d/36 rt 10]
```

where d is the accepted value of the diameter